# Understanding prototype object creation with 'Object.create()' instead of 'new' keyword

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I came to a code that contains these lines

```
var data = function() {
    function Metadata() { /*some initialization here*/ }

    Metadata.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);
    Metadata.prototype.constructor = Metadata;

    return Metadata;
}
```

I struggle to understand what is actually going on, and how to use the returning object. If I understand it correctly, `data` will now be an object that should be initialized like this

```
var d = new data()
```

But I don't understand the following lines and why `Object.create()` is used instead of the `new` keyword:

```
Metadata.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);
Metadata.prototype.constructor = Metadata;
```

What do they do? Are they necessary? And what is the difference between `Object.create` and `new` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JavaScript is a prototype-based language.** 
It means that it don't use the *class* keyword as in other languages. Instead JavaScript use *functions* as classes.
In your example the *data* variable can be assimilated to a *class*:

`var Data = function() { ... }`

**To create an instance of this class** we use the *new* keyword assigning the result of type object to a variable.

`var data = new Data()`

**Since ECMA Script 6** we can use the instantiation method `Object.create()` that create an uninitiated object with the specified prototype object and properties. It takes in argument the object which should be the prototype of the newly-created object. (It also copy the constructor)

So the following lines are a way to make Metadata extending the Backend object and keeps its own constructor:

```
// Metadata extends Backend
Metadata.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);
Metadata.prototype.constructor = Metadata;
```

---

**But this code is not exactly equivalent to** `Metadata.prototype = new Backend();`. See this example:

```
//Base class
var Backend = function(){ this.publicProperty='SomeValue'; }

//Extension class 1
var Metadata1 = function() { }
Metadata1.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);
Metadata1.prototype.constructor = Metadata1;

//Extension class 2
var Metadata2 = function() { }
Metadata2.prototype = new Backend();


/*
 *  Then the results are different (see code snippet at the end of this post)
 */
//result1 = 'undefined'
var data1 = new Metadata1();
var result1 = data1.publicProperty;

//result2 = 'SomeValue'
var data2 = new Metadata2();
var result2 = data2.publicProperty;
```

In fact both are very similar, the main difference is that `new` keyword actually runs constructor code, whereas `Object.create` will not execute code.

One other difference is that with `Object.create` you can create an object that doesn't inherit from anything (`Object.create(null)`).
Whereas if you do `Metadata.prototype = null` the newly created object will inherit from `Object.prototype`

---

**Note:** In some older browser (IE8 and below) you can use this equivalent code to `Object.create`:

```
Object.create = function(o){
    function F(){}
    F.prototype=o;
    return new F();
}
```

---

**Here is the working code snippet that shows the differences between the two approach**

```js
//Base class
var Backend = function(){ this.publicProperty='SomeValue'; }

//Extension class 1
var Metadata1 = function() { }
Metadata1.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);
Metadata1.prototype.constructor = Metadata1;

//Extension class 2
var Metadata2 = function() { }
Metadata2.prototype = new Backend();


//result: 'undefined'
var data1 = new Metadata1();
$("#result1").text("result1: " +  (typeof data1.publicProperty=='undefined' ? 'undefined' : data1.publicProperty));

//result: 'SomeValue'
var data2 = new Metadata2();
$("#result2").text("result2: " +  (typeof data2.publicProperty=='undefined' ? 'undefined' : data2.publicProperty));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is so very confusing and I am **so glad** ES6 inheritance semantics ("extends", constructor, "super") is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Those two lines are the prototypical way of having `Metadata` extend `Backend`.

Classes in JavaScript are defined as functions. If you define the `prototype` on a function, you can use the `new` keyword (or `Object.create`) to create an instance of the class. The functions/properties that are on the prototype will be on the new instance of the class you create.

In the above code, `Metadata.prototype` is being set to an instance of `Backend`, so `Metadata.prototype` will inherit call the methods/properties on `Backend.prototype`.

You can find more at [**Inheritance and the prototype chain**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: What is the difference between `Metadata.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);` and `Metadata.prototype = new Backend()` ?

Comment: When you use `Object.create` the constructor function won't be called. So if you only want to extend the prototype of `Backend` then `Object.create` makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript there are no classes, and instead we have constructors that can be called with the `new` keyword to create new objects, so we will get the same behavior as classes and instanciation.

And these two lines are used to express inheritance, and to make `Metadata` extends `Backend`, in the line:

```
Metadata.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);
```

We define the prototype of `Metadata`, object which should be the prototype of the newly-created object.

While in this line:

```
Metadata.prototype.constructor = Metadata;
```

We define the constructor of `Metadata` which will be used to create new instances of `Metadata`.

And inheritance can be tested like this:

```
var meta = new Metadata(); 

console.log('Is meta an instance of Metadata? ' + (meta instanceof Metadata)); // true
console.log('Is meta an instance of Backend? ' + (meta instanceof Backend)); // true
```

And you can find more about it with another example in the [**Object.create() documentaion**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) here.

Comment: `meta instanceof Backend` should be `true` as well.

Comment: @Leo Well pointed out, yes of course, I just missed it, I edited my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[**`Object.create`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is an ES6 method, it creates an object with the given object as prototype.

```
Metadata.prototype = Object.create(Backend.prototype);
```

So the above line means `Metadata` inherits all properties and methods from `Backend`. It's somehow similar to the following line before ES6:

```
Metadata.prototype = new Backend();
```

However, `Metadata` also inherits `constructor` property from `Backend`:

```
var metaData = new Metadata();
metaData.constructor; // function Backend()
```

This look weird because `metaData` is actually constructed with `Metadata`, so we fix it like this:

```
Metadata.prototype.constructor = Metadata;

var metaData = new Metadata();
metaData.constructor; // function Metadata()
```

Notice that this doesn't mess with `instanceof` operator:

```
metaData instanceof Metadata // true
metaData instanceof Backend  // true
```